# Constructive intermediate value theorem

Tags: analysis, logic, constructive-mathematics

I have given real numbers $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ such that $x_1 > x_2$ and $y_1 < y_2$. The the claim is that there exists some $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that $\lambda (x_1 - x_2) + (1-\lambda)(y_1-y_2) = 0$. In order to proof this, one needs ( at least in my opinion) the intermediate value theorem. But the intermediate value theorem does not hold in constructive mathematics (that is without the law of excluded middle; or constructive mathematics acts in intuitionistic logic). For a proof of this c.f. [this paper.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007211001990)
Is there any constructive way to show the above equation?

Comment: Anyway, the intermediate value theorem can be proved in a "constructive" way. (I put the "..." because I don't know a word about constructive mathematics). By bisecting iteratively, you **construct** a sequence that turns out to be Cauchy, and so it has a limit.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro the "construction" is not "constructive" enough for this purpose; it uses "either the left or the right works, so pick one, and ..." but constructions of this kind (especially with an infinite number of such choices) are forbidden in that context

Comment: @RichardRast: OK. On the other hand, if the function is differentiable, the Newton's method is available. That definitely *is* constructive. Am I right? This would provide a way of solving more general problems of the kind of this question

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I'm not an expert on constructive mathematics, but according to Dr. Google, Cauchy's theorem has a constructive proof. If Newton's method is constructively proved to converge to a solution, that should be valid. But I think the conditions on it converging might be nontrivial and require additional "constructive metadata" (like an explicit neighborhood around the point in which blah blah blah) ...

Comment: (cont.) but the accepted answer below is the intent of the discipline, to move away from general theorems that prove existence and toward constructions which (theoretically) give more information. Below we have the exact form of the answer, which in practice is often more useful than just knowing the answer exists.

Comment: Whether a proof is constructive or not depends on (and only on) which predicates you choose to be decidable by some sort of computing model.  The original constructive advocates (Bishop etc) had a set of predicates about real numbers they assumed were constructive, but give them a break it was decades before Turing Machines and Lambda Calculus etc were formalized.  So it doesn't actually make sense to say "the intermediate value theorem" is (or is not) constructive on its own.

Comment: @DanielV: Bishop's work on constructive analysis dates from the 1960s, more than 20 years after Turing defined what we now call Turing Machines and Curry or Church or Schonfinkel or whoever defined what we now call the $\lambda$-calculus. You are probably getting Bishop mixed up with Brouwer. Bishop knew exactly what it meant to say that the IVT is not constructive.

Comment: @RobArthan Oh thanks, I got the names mixed up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just solve the equation for $\lambda$. You get $\lambda =\frac {y_2-y_1}{x_1-x_2+y_2-y_1}$.

Answer (score 6):

You can explicitly solve the equation; 
$$\lambda= \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_1-x_2-y_1+y_2}.$$